# Can't receive UDP Packets in Java

Tags: java, networking, udp, multicast

I'm trying to receive some UDP packets on a Java MulticastSocket.

I can see the packets arriving in wireshark and the code works for other people, but not for me.

I honestly don't know what I'm doing wrong.

I have disabled my firewall and antivirus.

I'm running Windows 10 and IntelliJ 2017.2.5.

I'm creating a MulticastSocket with a portnumber (2000 or 2001) as a parameter.

My JRE is 1.8.0_152 and I'm using the JDK supplied by JetBrains.

This is how I'm creating the MulticastSocket:

```
this.socket = new MulticastSocket(this.portNum);
//this.socket = new MulticastSocket();
this.socket.setReceiveBufferSize(1 << 17);
this.socket.joinGroup(InetAddress.getByName(this.ip));
```

And, in a while loop, I try to receive data like this:

```
while(!this.socket.isClosed())
    {
        byte[] buffer = new byte[500];
        DatagramPacket incomingPacket = new DatagramPacket(buffer, buffer.length);
        try
        {
            this.socket.receive(incomingPacket);
            ...
```

Comment: try disabling your firewall

Comment: how much data are you trying to receive (or how much are you sending at once?  `1 << 17` is a 128kB receive buffer, I would use something much smaller but big enough to accommodate your packets.

Comment: What is the value of `this.ip`?

Answer (score 0):

Things to check are:

1. Make sure you bind your UDP socket to the interface you want to receive on. This is different for Windows and for Linux. For Windows: Bind to the IP address of the interface you want to receive on. On Linux bind to 0.0.0.0 to receive on all interfaces. (Receiving just on a specific interface is non-trivial on Linux.)
2. Make sure your `this.ip` is your multicast address, e.g. 224.1.2.3.

Comment: You can bind to 0.0.0.0 on all system. RFCs require it.

Answer (score -2):

The problem has been solved, it was an unrelated concurrency issue.